# Typescript use shared library

Tags: git, typescript, npm

When having different codebases how would I share code between them.
All code is in typescript and in continuous development.

I am looking for a simple solution.

Things I have tried:

### 1 using import statement with path to other project:

```
import { type } from '../../otherProj/src/type';
```

does not work:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../otherProj/src/type'
```

### 2 npm module

Installed locally using

```
npm i ../otherProj
```

Is problematic as I always have to update the version of the library on each change or I have to manually uninstall / reinstall the library.

### 3 git submodule / subtree

Using a git submodule.

### 4 Softlink / Directory Junction

As we are on Windows we are right now using the `mklink /D /J`

Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

> 2 npm module

Use `npm link` to link the module.

## Docs

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: So, assuming my modules are private and only used by projects which are also using typescript would I create some kind of source-package or compile the library separate?

Comment: what module?? we are talking about `shared library`, are you suggesting to publish it to npm every time?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting up a gulp-task that watches the code base in the primary location and copies both the source and compiled output to the secondary project / target.  The shared library is located in the root of both projects and have the same relative paths.

At the target I have .gitignore'd the copied source.

This works nicely, but have the **major drawback that symbol references in the editor leads me to edit the mirrored code**, not the managed source.  This might be improved by using a git "submodule" approach, where both trees will will be managed, but I dropped it as it seemed to add complexity and source server dependencies.

Coming from .net with compiled and shared assemblies this has turned out to be a surprisingly difficult issue, and I suspect that trying to replicate this behavior i Typescript might simply not the right way to do it?

```
function compileUtils() {
    // Tried to use the tool syncy for this, but it did not work with "../", had to revert to manual sync.
    //   NB: This will break when bad files are removed and renamed.
    return gulp.src(utilsPath)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./utils'));
}

function compileBuiltUtils() {
    // Copy of the above, copies the built utils files
    return gulp.src(utilsBuiltPath)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/utils'));
}
```

Comment: BTW: Another issue with the "watch and copy" approach is that it might not be possible to use on remote server where you don't have both code bases - at the same relative location.

Comment: I think a softlink is way superior to a gulp task which copies and watches. What do you think?

Comment: @Thomas I think you might be right.  But the softlink requires some specific setup on new machines, and causes the same, or more, problems on deployment to external build servers.  I don't think any option is particularly good.